# Analog for '&' with duplicates

Tags: ruby

From Ruby documentation:

> **ary & other_ary → new_ary**
>
> Set Intersection —
>   Returns a new array containing elements common to the two arrays,
>   excluding any duplicates. The order is preserved from the original
>   array.

But is there a **built-in** method to do the same thing **including duplicates**?

Test case:

```
ary = [2, 7, 3, 7]
other_ary = [7, 2, 7, 4]
new_ary == [2, 7, 7]
```

Comment: From what it looks like, you want to exclude non-duplicates from the array.  Is that correct?

Comment: No. I want to return a new array containing elements common to the two arrays, including duplicates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution below is not the most elegant one, but it returns the proper answer in any case:

```
[ary, other_ary].map { |e| e.group_by { |e| e } } # &:itself since 2.3
                .reduce { |memo, h| memo.merge(h) do |k, o, n|
                                      [o.count, n.count].min
                                    end } # merge to count
                .select { |_, v| Integer === v } # select only merged
                .flat_map { |k, v| [k] * v } # produce a result
```

Or, more elegant, mutating arrays:

```
a1, a2 = [ary, other_ary].map(&:dup) # to keep originals intact
loop.inject([]) do |memo|
  break memo if a1.empty?
  memo << (a2.delete_at(a2.index a1.pop) rescue nil)
end.compact
#⇒ [7, 7, 2]
```

or even:

```
a1, a2 = [ary, other_ary].map(&:dup) # to keep originals intact
loop.each_with_object([]) do |_, memo|
  break memo if a1.empty?
  a2.index(a1.pop).tap { |i| memo << a2.delete_at(i) if i }
end
```

Comment: Your first line is somewhat like, "You'll probably say 'no', but would you go to the dance with me?".

Comment: I appologize. The previous approach fails with pairs like `[2, 0, 0, 0]`, `[2, 2, 2, 3]` where the number of duplicates in `other_ary` is higher than in `ary`. And your code handles it.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this ?

```
ary.select{ |a| other_ary.include? a }
#=> [2, 7, 7]
```

Comment: What is the expected result, when `ary` includes two `7`, but `other_ary` only one?

Comment: if ary includes two `7`, the result will be [7,7], if ary includes one `7` and the other includes both, the result will be [7].

Comment: @spickermann Bartek got my question right. His solution is simple, elegant, fast and passed all my specs.

Comment: @ViktorDanilov Your specs might be wrong. What is the expected output for `[2,2,2,3] and [2]` — I bet it’d be `[2]`, while the answer above will produce `[2,2,2]`.

Comment: @mudasobwa in my case arrays always have `.size == 4`, so other_ary in my case will be `[2, 0, 0, 0]`. And the example you gave to me is exactly what I'm expecting :P

Comment: Then you gave a wrong description of the intended result: you are looking not for the duplicates, but for all elements from the first array, that appear at least once in the second array. Please modify the OP so that no further readers are cheated.

Comment: @mudasobwa I would love to accept your suggested edit :)

Comment: This is up to you to make a question clear, we are here not to fix your glitches. As a matter of fact, the re-stated question has more clear and fast robust solution: `ary - (ary - other_ary)` which was given by @user000001 (now deleted.)

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of the problem is that you are given two arrays, `a` and `b` and wish to return a third that contains `n` copies of each element `e` present in both `a` and `b`, where `n = [a.count(e), a.count(e)].max`.

Suppose

```
a = [3,1,2,1,0,1]
b = [1,2,4,2,4,6]
```

I suggest you perform the following three steps.

*Construct a counting hash for each array*

```
ha = a.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |n,h| h[n] += 1 }
  #=> {3=>1, 1=>3, 2=>1, 0=>1} 
hb = b.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |n,h| h[n] += 1 }
  #=> {1=>1, 2=>2, 4=>2, 6=>1}
```

*Determine the elements common to both arrays*

```
common_elements = a & b
  #=> [1, 2]
```

*Construct the desired array*

```
common_elements.flat_map { |n| [n]*[ha[n], hb[n]].max }
  #=> [1, 1, 1, 2, 2]
```